# Image automatically set to recyclerview items those having no images in data after scrolling when using pagination

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-paging

when using pagination in recyclerview functionality woking fine, but after scrolling recyclerview images set to all recyclerview items those having no image data from api. 
How to avoid it..

I will attach my adapter and activity code.

Adapter file

```
public class TestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
private Context context;
private List<Homework> homeworkList;
private static final int LOADING = 0;
private static final int ITEM = 1;
private boolean isLoadingAdded = false;
private Image_ViewpagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

public TestAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.homeworkList = new LinkedList<>();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

    switch (viewType) {
        case ITEM:
            View viewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cv_homework_list, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new HomeworkViewHolder(viewItem);
            break;
        case LOADING:
            View viewLoading = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cv_item_progress, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new LoaderViewHolder(viewLoading);
            break;
    }
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Homework homework = homeworkList.get(position);

    switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
        case ITEM:
            List<String> homeworkImages = new ArrayList<>();
            homeworkImages.clear();

            HomeworkViewHolder homeworkViewHolder = (HomeworkViewHolder) holder;
            homeworkViewHolder.tvSubjectName.setText(homework.getSubject().getName());

            String homeworkTitle = homework.getTitle();
            homeworkViewHolder.tvHomeworkTitle.setText(homeworkTitle);

            String homeworkDetails = homework.getDescription();
            homeworkViewHolder.tvHomeworkDetails.setText(homeworkDetails);

            // ----------------  image related code ------------
            for (int i = 0; i < homework.getAttachments().size(); i++)
            {
                String im = homework.getAttachments().get(i).getFilename();
                homeworkImages.add(im);
            }

            if(!String.valueOf(homeworkImages.size()).equals("0"))
            {
                pagerAdapter = new Image_ViewpagerAdapter(context,homeworkImages);
                homeworkViewHolder.vpImages.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
                homeworkViewHolder.indicator.attachToPager(homeworkViewHolder.vpImages);
                pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            break;

        case LOADING:
            LoaderViewHolder loaderViewHolder = (LoaderViewHolder) holder;
            loaderViewHolder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return homeworkList == null ? 0 : homeworkList.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return (position == homeworkList.size() - 1 && isLoadingAdded) ? LOADING : ITEM;
}

public void addLoadingFooter() {
    isLoadingAdded = true;
    add(new Homework());
}

public void removeLoadingFooter() {
    isLoadingAdded = false;

    int position = homeworkList.size() - 1;
    Homework homework = getItem(position);

    if (homework != null) {
        homeworkList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
}

public void add(Homework homework) {
    homeworkList.add(homework);
    notifyItemInserted(homeworkList.size() - 1);
}

public void addAll(List<Homework> homeworkResult) {
    for (Homework result : homeworkResult) {
        add(result);
    }
}

public Homework getItem(int position) {
    return homeworkList.get(position);
}

public class HomeworkViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView tvSubjectName,tvHomeworkTitle,tvHomeworkDetails,tvHomeworkOld;
    private ViewPager vpImages;
    private ScrollingPagerIndicator indicator;

    public HomeworkViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tvHomeworkOld = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_homework_date);
        tvSubjectName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_subject_name);
        tvHomeworkTitle =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_homework_title);
        tvHomeworkDetails =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_homework_details);
        vpImages = itemView.findViewById(R.id.vp_images);
        indicator = itemView.findViewById(R.id.scrolling_indicator);
    }
}

public class LoaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    public LoaderViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        progressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    }
}
```

}

Activity file

```
public class Homework extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerViewHomework;
ProgressBar progressBar;
TextView tvNotFound;
private TestAdapter adapter;
Retrofit retrofit;
Api_Services apiServices;
private static final int PAGE_START = 1;
private boolean isLoading = false;
private boolean isLastPage = false;
private int TOTAL_PAGES = 100;
private int currentPage = PAGE_START;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_homework);

    retrofit = NetworkClient.getRetrofitClient(Homework.this);
    apiServices = retrofit.create(Api_Services.class);

    view = findViewById(R.id.included_layout);
    ivNotFound  = view.findViewById(R.id.ivNotFound);
    tvNotFound  = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_not_found);
    mbtnRetry  = view.findViewById(R.id.mbtn_retry);

    LayoutAnimationController animation = AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(Homework.this, R.anim.layout_animation_fall_down);

    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    recyclerViewHomework =  findViewById(R.id.rv_homework);

    recyclerViewHomework.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewHomework.setLayoutAnimation(animation);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManagerHomework = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerViewHomework.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerHomework);
    recyclerViewHomework.addItemDecoration(new EqualSpacingItemDecoration(16,
            EqualSpacingItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
    recyclerViewHomework.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

    adapter = new TestAdapter(this);
    recyclerViewHomework.setAdapter(adapter);

    recyclerViewHomework.addOnScrollListener(new PaginationScrollListener(layoutManagerHomework) {
        @Override
        protected void loadMoreItems() {
            isLoading = true;
            currentPage += 1;
            loadNextPageHomework();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLastPage() {
            return isLastPage;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLoading() {
            return isLoading;
        }
    });

    loadFirstPageHomework();

}

private void loadFirstPageHomework() {
    Call<Homeworks> getHomework = apiServices.getHomeworkList(
            prefManager.getDataFromSharedPreferences().get(Select_children.selectedChilderPosition).getBatchId(),
            currentPage,5,"date_of_homework","desc");

    getHomework.enqueue(new Callback<Homeworks>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Homeworks> call, Response<Homeworks> response)
        {
            List<Homework> listHomework = response.body().getHomeworks();
            adapter.addAll(listHomework);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if (currentPage <= TOTAL_PAGES) adapter.addLoadingFooter();
            else isLastPage = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Homeworks> call, Throwable t)
        {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}

private void loadNextPageHomework() {
    Call<Homeworks> getHomework = apiServices.getHomeworkList(
            prefManager.getDataFromSharedPreferences().get(Select_children.selectedChilderPosition).getBatchId(),
            currentPage,5,"date_of_homework","desc");

    getHomework.enqueue(new Callback<Homeworks>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Homeworks> call, Response<Homeworks> response)
        {
            isLoading = false;

            if(!response.body().isSuccess())
            {
                isLastPage = true;
                adapter.removeLoadingFooter();
                Toast.makeText(Homework.this, "No Homework Remaining", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            adapter.removeLoadingFooter();

            List<Homework> listHomework = response.body().getHomeworks();
            adapter.addAll(listHomework);

            if (currentPage != TOTAL_PAGES) adapter.addLoadingFooter();
            else isLastPage = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Homeworks> call, Throwable t)
        {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

}

please suggest proper way for pagination for above issue.

[image: Before Scrolling view]
[image: After SCrolling view]

Comment: i don't exactly understand what you mean, but maybe your problem is, that you don't set the image or clear it, in case of LOADING. If you don't do that, you have old recycled images displayed, because the view isn't necessary recreated

Comment: @DominikWuttke , sorry but i dont know where to refresh view in LOADING, I have uploaded my view screenshots. please check this.